# Calling new Activity from Menu item and getting NPE when setting setOnClickListener on a button

Tags: android

I am a starter in android development and trying some hands on.

**Context** :
Written a basic app which has multiple menu options and all the options have an activity associated to them , So when a user click on menu option then I am trying to start an activity , which has some basic form widgets like Edit text ,spinner and buttons. I was able to navigate from one activity to other using menu options

**Problem**:
I am getting below error while setting click listner to submit button

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference.

I tried debugging the application and found that my widgets are not getting initialized , I have tried adding this code to onCreate, OnStart, OnResume
But getting same results

Below is the activity code(This is not main Activity)

```
  public class AddCar extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText modelName;

    private Button addCar;
    private Button refreshBtn;
    private Spinner chooseBrandName;

    public final String LOG_TAG = AddCar.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_add, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getAllWidgets();
        addListenerOnSubmitButton();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void addListenerOnSubmitButton(){

        addCar.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        String modelNameText = modelName.getText().toString();
                        String carBrand=chooseBrandName.getSelectedItem().toString();

                        Log.d(LOG_TAG,modelNameText);
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG,carBrand);

                    }
                }
        );
    }

    public void getAllWidgets(){

        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"getAllWidgets called");

        addCar=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCarAdd);
        refreshBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCarRefresh);
        modelName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.modelName);
        chooseBrandName=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.brandNames);


    }
}
```

and the xml code for this activity is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#000000">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.40"
        android:text="@string/CAR_BRAND"
        android:textColor="#CCCCCC" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/brandNames"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/brand_names"
        android:prompt="@string/CHOOSE_CAR"
        android:layout_weight="0.60"
        android:background="#CCCCCC" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.40"
        android:text="@string/CAR_MODEL_NAME"
        android:textColor="#CCCCCC"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/modelName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.60"
        android:ems="10"
        android:background="#CCCCCC" />
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.40"
        android:textColor="#CCCCCC"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCarAdd"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.375"
        android:text="@string/CAR_ADD_BUTTON" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCarRefresh"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.375"
        android:text="@string/CAR_REFRESH_BUTTON" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button is null, you're getting a NullPointerException because you're trying to call setOnClickListener on a null button.

The reason your button is null, is because it's not actually being found in your getAllWidgets() call. The reason for that is because you're not calling setContentView() in onCreate.

Try this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);

}
```